# extract values from multiple lists

Tags: r

I have several named number lists with  output as follow:

list1

```
A         B       C      
5.0      1.29    3.54
```

list2

```
A         B       C      
6.0     2.29    4.54
```

I would like to compute median of all values corresponding to same name. For example median of all values corresponding to "A". 
My idea is to extract value corresponding to "A" from each list and create a data frame. How do I do this?

Else, is there a better way to compute the median?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a list or a vector? can you paste the `dput(list1)`?

Comment: dput(list1) gives output:  c(A =5, B = 1.29, C = 3.45)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution creates a list of lists, then uses sapply to retrieve the "A" element into a vector, and then take the median.

```
list1 <- list(5,1.29,3.54)
list2 <- list(6,2.29,4.54)
list3 <- list(7,3.29,4.54)

names(list1) <- c("A","B","C")
names(list2) <- c("A","B","C")
names(list3) <- c("A","B","C")


##
median_a <- median(sapply(list(list1, list2, list3), function(i)i[["A"]]))
median_b <- median(sapply(list(list1, list2, list3), function(i)i[["b"]]))

##Alternatively you can put everything in a dataframe, and then take the median using apply
df <- data_frame_of_values <- data.frame(
    a = sapply(list(list1, list2, list3), function(i)i[["A"]]),
    b = sapply(list(list1, list2, list3), function(i)i[["B"]]),
    c = sapply(list(list1, list2, list3), function(i)i[["C"]])
)

apply(df, MARGIN = 2,median) ##This retrieves the medians
```

Comment: why cant you just do `c(by(b<-unlist(c(list1,list2,list3)),names(b),median))` or rather: `a<-unlist(c(list1,list2,list3)); tapply(a,names(a),median)`???

Answer (score 0):

this isn't pretty, but it works. makes use of `as.data.frame()`, `t()`, and `summarize_all()` from the tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)

lst <- list(c(A = 5.0, B = 1.29, C = 3.54), c(A = 6.0, B = 2.29, C = 4.54))

lst %>% 
  as.data.frame(col.names = 1:length(lst)) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  summarize_all(median)
```